# How to create a popup upon logging into Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, popups

I wanted to know how to create a popup screen, right after logging into Windows XP.

In my case I'd like to warn users that if they need to download something, they need to communicate with the computer administrator (me).

Answer (score 3):

Windows Xp includes a feature as part of the security features to be able to pop up a message when users log on.

> Specifies a text message that is displayed to users when they log on.
>
> This text is often used for legal reasons, for example, to warn users about the ramifications of misusing company information or to warn them that their actions may be audited.

From [this page at Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/577.mspx?mfr=true).

Now... how do you get at it and change it?  Start Menu -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Settings.  Once it is open, expand Local Policies, and examine Security Options.  Scroll Down to the Interactive Logon settings.  You will see `Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on`.  Either double click that, or right click it and choose properties.  You will see the text block there on the first tab "Local Security Policy".  Now, I know it says "attempting to log on" but if you click the second tab there, Explain this policy, you will see it is to display something AFTER they have logged on.

Comment: Niice!! What about when a user clicks the internet icon, such as chrome or mozilla, so a message pops up?

Comment: @Carlos that would be a different question, with a different answer.  What you asked about initially, turned out to be a built in feature with Windows.  What you are asking about now, is not.  I suppose you could alter each browser shortcut to start a batch file that would bring up a command prompt with a message, and a "press any key to continue" to start the browser.